# Video View VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i try to play a video in a VideoView, therefore i used the following code:

```
PlayVideo();
}


private void PlayVideo(){
    String urlPath = "android.resource://love.dominikhartlug.clate/"+R.raw.vido;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlPath);

    vw.setVideoURI(uri);
    vw.start();
}
}
```

i return always the following error message:

```
.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
```

if i list all files from my raw folder, the file vido.mp4 does exist.

does anyone have a solution?

Comment: are you initializing vw before going to set url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you initialized vw it looks like you haven't initialize vw that's its trowing null pointerbecause vw is null

Comment: no i initialized it in my oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

Have you used findViewById to link it?

Comment: i initialized it in my oncreate method

Comment: Bro just use normal link instead of what you are using here ... like “www.website.com/videos/sample.mp4”